# Extract content between pipes using RE2 Regexp_Extract

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I have data in certain dimensions that can look like this:

```
this|is|an|example
withoutpipe
only1|pipe
```

I want to extract the data between the pipes using RE2 RegEx.

I have tried it with `[^|]+` but this does not seem to work.

I want every word to get extracted and need help trying to figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

Google Data Studio uses the [RE2 Syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) for Regular Expressions, and the escape sequence for special characters is:

```
\\
```

Created a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/2b02f98d-9301-47c7-ae4e-a80f66f94970) (Google Sheets Embedded) to demonstrate using the [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058) function:

> **1) Nothing**
>
> ```
> REGEXP_REPLACE(Field, "\\|", "")
> ```
>
> **2) Space**
>
> ```
> REGEXP_REPLACE(Field, "\\|", " ")
> ```
>
> **3) Comma & Space**
>
> ```
> REGEXP_REPLACE(Field, "\\|", ", ")
> ```

[image]